# Derivative of Softmax function

Tags: python, machine-learning, softmax

I am trying to compute the derivative of softmax function. I have a **2d numpy array** and I am calculating the softmax for the array along **axis 1**. My python code for the same is:

```
def softmax(z):

     return np.exp(z) / np.sum(np.exp(z), axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

Now my python code for calculating the derivative of softmax equation is:

```
def softmax_derivative(Q):

    x=softmax(Q)
    s=x.reshape(-1,1)
    return (np.diagflat(s) - np.dot(s, s.T))
```

Is this the correct approach ?

Also if my numpy array has a shape (3,3) then what would be the shape of the array returned by the softmax derivative? Would the shape of the array returned be (9,9) ?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36280783/2206251

Answer (score -1):

I would subtract the maximum value of z and do something like:

```py
def softmax(z):
     exps = np.exp(z - z.max())
     return exps/np.sum(exps)
```

to improve stability, but, otherwise what you are doing is correct.