# The derivative of Softmax outputs really large shapes

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, backpropagation, softmax

I am creating a basic, and also my first neural network on handwritten digit recognition without any framework (like Tensorflow, PyTorch...) using the **Backpropagation algorithm**.

My NN has 784 inputs and 10 outputs. So for the last layer, I have to use Softmax.

Because of some memory errors, I have right now my images in shape **(300, 784)** and my labels in shape **(300, 10)**
After that I am calculating loss from **Categorical Cross-entropy**.
Now we are getting to my problem. In Backpropagation, I need manually compute the first derivative of an activation function. I am doing it like this:

```
dAl = -(np.divide(Y, Al) - np.divide(1 - Y, 1 - Al))
#Y = test labels
#Al - Activation value from my last layer
```

And after that my Backpropagation can start, so the last layer is softmax.

```
def SoftmaxDerivative(dA, Z):
        #Z is an output from np.dot(A_prev, W) + b
              #Where A_prev is an activation value from previous layer
              #W is weight and b is bias
        #dA is the derivative of an activation function value
        x = activation_functions.softmax(dA)
        s = x.reshape(-1,1)
        dZ = np.diagflat(s) - np.dot(s, s.T)
        return dZ
```

**1. Is this function working properly?**

In the end, I would like to compute derivatives of weights and biases, So I am using this:

```
dW = (1/m)*np.dot(dZ, A_prev.T)
#m is A_prev.shape[1] -> 10
db = (1/m)*np.sum(dZ, axis = 1, keepdims = True)
```

BUT it fails on dW, because dZ.shape is **(3000, 3000)** (compare to A_prev.shape, which is (300,10))
So from this I assume, that there are only 3 possible outcomes.

1. My Softmax backward is wrong
2. dW is wrong
3. I have some other bug completely somewhere else

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: hey - when dealing with shape issues ( or asking for help with some ), it's always useful to add the dimensions of all tensors involved :). couple small observations (1) your first derivative seems to not check for 0 divisions, (2) your SoftmaxDerivative() doesn't use the Z input at all. Assuming dA.shape = (300, 10), the correct output shape should be (300, 300) .. so maybe you are multiplying somewhere to end up with dA.shape = (3000, 10) somewhere..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem recently. I'm not sure but maybe this question will help you: [Softmax derivative in NumPy approaches 0 (implementation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279904/softmax-derivative-in-numpy-approaches-0-implementation)